# read value from property file in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, resourcebundle

I create a springmvc web application. I want to read property file. I have a properties file 
app.properties located in resources

```
p.id=1
p.name=test
```

I have a class Constant.java

```
public class Constant{

    public static PropertyFile{
        public static final String APP="resources/app";
    }
    public static PropertyKey{
        public static final String P_ID = "p.id";
        public static final String P_Name = "p.name";
    }

}
```

I have an AppSetting.java

```
public class AppSetting{
       private static final ResourceBundle resource =
            ResourceBundle.getBundle(Constants.PropertyFile.APP);
       public String getId(){
        return resource.getString(Constant.PropertyKey.P_ID);
        }

}
```

when I called it AppSetting.getId(); it cannot find resource. Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried `APP="/resources/app";`

Comment: try /WEB-INF/resources/app for your String APP

Comment: try to change the address in the APP variable

Comment: You may want to try:

    ResourceBundle.getBundle("app", Locale.getDefault())

Depending on your locale settings getBundle finds the properties file using the behaviour described here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)